# Como pasar una lista a una tabla incrementable

Tags: javascript, html, python, django, django-models

Tengo el siguente codigo:

el Script y el boton funcionan bien sin el parametro de `regla` pero al agregarlo deja de servir

mi script

```
  function agregarFila(String){
  document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td class="counterCell text-center"></td> <td style="width:70%"> {% render_field form.regla class="form-control"  %} </td>  <td style="width:30%"> {% render_field form.validacion class="form-control"  %}</td>' ; 
}
```

pero al pasarle el parametro : `{% render_field form.regla class="form-control"  %}`

el boton deja de funcionar

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" style="border-radius: 20px ;" onclick="agregarFila()"><span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span> Agregar Fila </button>
```

mi models

```
REGLA = (
    ('1', 'opcion 1)'),
    ('2', 'opcion 2)'),
    ('3', 'opcion 3'),
    ('4', 'opcion 4'),
    ('5', 'opcion 5')
    
)
class Regla(models.Model):
    
    id_regla = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes_banco/')
    regla = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=45, choices=REGLA)
    validacion = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

Comment: Puedes revisar la salida HTML que se genera en esa linea `document.getElementById("tablaprueba")...` debe haber algo en el codigo generado que rompe o invalida el string

Comment: a que se riefiere con salida con salida HTML ? aun soy algo nuevo en esto

Comment: Revisa la pagina generada desde el browser, y revisa el codigo fuente que se genero desde django (click derecho sobre la pagina y seleccionar "Ver codigo fuente")

Comment: En el codigo fuente si se logra ver que trae los las opciones de la lista, deberia buscar algo en especifico ?

Comment: Fijate en la consola de javascript, si aparece algun error y comparte el mensaje que aparezca.

Comment: aparecen 2 errores :

1.```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined ```  
2. ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que el codigo generado no pueda incrustarse directamente el el string de javascript  por incluir caracters invalidos (uso de comillas, saltos de linea, etc) .

Puedes generar el contenido en codigo HTML normal en un bloque template, y luego incrustarlo sin problema:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none">
  <td class="counterCell text-center"></td>
  <td style="width:70%"> {% render_field form.regla class="form-control"  %} </td>
  <td style="width:30%"> {% render_field form.validacion class="form-control"  %}</td>
</div>
<script>
 function agregarFila(String){
  document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML ; 
 }

</script>
```

Comment: esto soluciono el problema de la invocacion de los datos, pero si agrego el <div> dentro de <table>   este deja de servir

Comment: El `div` debes generarlo fuera del `<table>` si este codigo esta dentro, antes de este por ejemplo, es un elemento independiente